# How to allow slashes in single posts when i click in the edit permalink button

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls, seo

I have a problem, I have this **slug**:

**my-site/blog/wordpress-a-style-of-life/**

and this other:

**my-site/blog/best-tips-of-wordpress/**

i have to improve SEO editing both permalink like this:

**my-site/blog/wordpress/**

**my-site/blog/wordpress/best-tips/**

I am trying to edit the permalink of both posts in the admin area, but i don´t get anything, and i dont know how solve this.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add additional "folders" in the post editing screen. You would need to change your permalink structure, so that Posts include the Category in the URL. In Settings > Permalinks, choose "Custom Structure" and paste

`/%category%/%postname%/`

Keep in mind this will change all your Post URLs, so you'll need to add redirects. Also keep in mind small tweaks to permalinks like this don't often give you a big SEO boost so depending on how many posts you would need to redirect, it may be worth investing more effort into optimizing the on-page content rather than changing permalinks.

Comment: Thank you WebElaine, I had thought about use categories, the problem is that this structure only  will be used in some post with the same thematic... and with categories i will have another problem, the original post must have this structure: my-site/blog/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across this problem yesterday and used [this plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) to great effect (Wich is not related to me in any way).

This allows you to create completely custom permalinks for posts and categories.

Comment: And that plugin work for you properly? i have tested it and when i try to go to that url if the url have slashes added wordpress dont go to single.php it use archive.php template.

Comment: I had some 404s but a adjusted my permalink structure … that was all. Are you sure that this problem is the plugins fault? … naturally there may be errors when you create a url that is already taken by the system … Can you change the url to something unique and test it again?