# How can I have a page's permalink include my custom post type's slug?

Tags: permalinks

I have a custom post type that has the slug `mycpt`, so URLs for posts of this custom post type are like `www.site.com/mycpt/the-name-of-a-post`.

What I want to do is create a page (using Pages>Add New) that will also have `mycpt` as the slug, so the URL of the page will be like `www.site.com/mycpt/the-name-of-this-new-page`. I tried editing the page's permalink to be `mycpt/the-name-of-this-new-page`, but WordPress just changes it to `mycpt-the-name-of-this-new-page`.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17613789/9159152)'s a similar question to yours.

Comment: Thanks @JackJohansson . One problem though is that post shows how to set the base directory for ALL pages, not a single page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow slashes in single posts when i click in the edit permalink button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307604/how-to-allow-slashes-in-single-posts-when-i-click-in-the-edit-permalink-button)